# How to get Selected Items back back into the checkedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkedlistbox, checklistbox

I have checkedListBox called [CLB_CONTROLLER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cULdf.jpg) that is loaded to the page to display names instead of ID:
This information is stored in `dbo.CHIPSET`

```
public void loadCategory()
{
    CLB_CONTROLLER.DataSource = catg.getCategories();
    CLB_CONTROLLER.DisplayMember = "CHIPSET";
    CLB_CONTROLLER.ValueMember = "CHIPSET_ID";
}
```

Then I would insert data into the DB as string. This information is stored in `dbo.MYDB`

```
//LOOP THROUGH CONTROLLER CHECKED ITEMS TO INSERT ALL SELECTED
string chip = "";
for (int i = 0; i < CLB_CONTROLLER.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{
    if (chip == "")
    {
        chip = CLB_CONTROLLER.GetItemText(CLB_CONTROLLER.CheckedItems[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        chip += ", " + CLB_CONTROLLER.GetItemText(CLB_CONTROLLER.CheckedItems[i]);
    }
}
```

So far so good… Now I want to create Update feature… When user selects cell from the `DataGrid` , I want to auto populate all `textboxes`, `CheckBoxes` etc. on the page. So I am trying to figure out how can I do that with `CLB_CONTROLLER` mentioned above.
The Update is looking inside `dbo.MYDB` and the column 2 `CHIPSET` which is now a string (inserted with code above). I have this code below, but when I click on `DataGrid`, nothing happens inside the `CLB_CONTROLLER`

```
//CHECK IF CONTROLLER CONTAINES CONTENT, THEN SELLECT APPROPRIATE CHECK BOX
string con = DGV_AOC.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
string[] convalues = con.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < convalues.Length; i++)
{
    convalues[i] = convalues[i].Trim();
}

for (int i = 0; i < CLB_CONTROLLER.Items.Count; i++)
{
    CLB_CONTROLLER.SetItemChecked(i, false);//First uncheck the old value!
    for (int x = 0; x < convalues.Length; x++)
    {
        if (CLB_CONTROLLER.Items[i].ToString() == convalues[x].ToString())
        {
            //Check only if they match! 
            CLB_CONTROLLER.SetItemChecked(i, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the usage of `ValueMember` if you store item's text in a comma separated string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have filled the `CheckedListBox` with `a,b,c,d,e,f` for example as item texts.

Then you can set checked items based on a comma separated list this way:

```
var itemsToSelect = "a,c,d";
var items = itemsToSelect.Split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var b = items.Contains(checkedListBox1.GetItemText(checkedListBox1.Items[i]));
    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, b);
}
```

Also you can get checked items in a comma-separated string this way:

```
var selectedItems = string.Join(",",
    checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<object>()
        .Select(x => checkedListBox1.GetItemText(x)));
```

Comment: The items would keep adding to the `checkedListBox1` based on user selection on the `dataGrid` view which is not exactly what I want. And I say that because let's say user mistakenly selects wrong chipset and wanted to update selection,  with proposed approach above, they would not be able to do that because complete list would not be available. I wanted them to be able to see complete list just like shown on my picture above but at the same time, when they select something from the `dataGrid`, appropriate items would be checked.

Comment: In my code `a,b,c,d,e,f` is complete list for example.

Comment: As an example, I can achieve what I want with my code above if I create new let's say `checkedListBox1` and instead of getting list populated from the DB, I manually add items to the `checkedListBox1`. Then my code above would work. But I am trying to reuse the same `CLB_CONTROLLER` checkBox I already have

Comment: You can fill the `CheckedListBox` using whatever logic which you have. The example code is completely independent from the way that you fill `CheckedListBox`. It just accept the comma separated list and select them in `CheckedListBox`. Also it can convert `CheckedItems` back to comma separated string.

Comment: Your users should be able to choose between all items. Also `CheckedListBox` should be able to show checked items, based on the comma separated list which you have in the cell. Also you should be able to put back checked items as comma separated list. The example code has nothing to do with list of items and it assumes you have filled the `CheckedListBox` with items. I believe, it's *exactly* what you are looking for

Comment: Got it... Just checked and it works as you have explained. Thank you SO MUCH for all this effort :-)